# node-ffi : Dynamic Linking Error

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-ffi

I have a C++ method (which role is killing some processes), in a library Risk.dll.

On the other hand, I am developing a web-application (using Nodejs and AngularJS), running on Google Chrome.
When I click on a button through the browser, I would like to be able to call the C++ function, through my app.js file.

I have decided to use Node-ffi, but I have the error :

```
Error: Dynamic Linking Error: "Risk.dll":
```

Here is my code on javascript :

```
var ffi = require('ffi')
//Kill Server
socket.on('killserver', function(date){

    var cTest =  ffi.Library("Risk", {
        "DateModified":["long", ["string"] ]
    });

    var res = cTest.DateModified(date);
    console.log(res)
});
```

In C++, I have done

```
extern C{
}
```

And I want to add that my file Risk.dll is in the same file than the file server.js I run with Node when I want to use my app.

Any clue ?

Comment: Is the dll compatible with your Node instance? I mean 32/64bit

Answer (score 2):

Try the 64-bit compiler which is normally found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe`